# Retrieving information from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got two tables in my database, one like

```
**ID / muscle group name**  
1 / arms  
2 / chest  
3 / legs
```

and another table like this

```
**ID / muscle_name / muscle_group_id**  
1 / biceps / 1  
2 / triceps / 1  
3 / extensor / 1  
4 / flexor / 1
```

How can I get the data from my database so that I can retrieve the information like

```
echo $result['arms'][0]
```

(to get `muscle_group_id` for `arms`)

and then iterate over all the muscles in the arm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

1.Connect

2.Select database

3.Make query

4.Cycle on the result and fetch array to get the row

Here is example:

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```